# How do I track a conversion in Google Analytics Based on Form Submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-analytics

I have a form on a single landing page for my website. I am using Google Analytics on my website. When the form is submitted, I would like to track this in Google Analytics somehow, as a conversion (or some other statistic).

Has anyone done something similar to this? I realize there are custom events, such as video clicks/etc, but I'd like to look at form submissions, or how to setup a custom event for the form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To track a form submission, you might want to look at [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events).

If you are using jQuery, you might have something similar to:

```
<form action="thank-you.html" method="POST">
   <!-- Some inputs -->
   <!-- ... -->

   <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Then you could track Form interactions using:

```
(function ($) {
   $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
      // Temporarily prevent submission of the form:
      event.preventDefault();

      // Keep a reference to the form:
      var form = $(this);

      ga('send', 'event', {
         'eventCategory': 'Form',    // Event Category (Required).
         'eventAction': 'Submit',    // Event Action (Required).
         'eventLabel': 'Form Title', // Event Label (Optional).
         'hitCallback': function () {
            // Once the Event has been sent to Google Analytics, submit the form:
            form.submit();
         }
      });
   });
})(jQuery)
```

You could then use this Event as Goals in Google Analytics to get specific insights about Form submissions: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012040?hl=en